# Google Chrome how can i capture RTSP stream?

Tags: google-chrome, gstreamer, vlc, npapi, v4l2

In Windows7, 8.1. With Google Chrome how can i capture RTSP stream? 
GStreamer + V4L2loopback works in Linux but is there any way to make V4L2loopback or similar for Windows? so that under Windows we can do video sink and capture that sink in Chrome?

`... ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0`

(unfortunately i cant use streaming for 720p, 1080p, 4K captures, as streaming is very slow)

Answer (score 0):

You cant natively && real-time (like you could with NPAPI) as of 13 May, 2015.

Ask Chrome Team to provide alternative for this ([ask here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list))